# get instance of another class from another file

Tags: swift

I can't seem to be able to get an instance of a class from a file. Here is what I'm attempting

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,....{
....
.....
  func testPrint(){
     println("It worked")
  }

}
```

vcAddItem.swift

```
class vcAdditem: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,..{
  let test = viewController()
  test.testPrint()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Compile Sources section in Build phases of your target. See if ViewController is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a typo 'viewController()' rather than with capital V 'ViewController()' is that the problem?  Check that both files are associated with the same target, and that there are no other errors (e.g. unclosed brackets)